# Regex pattern to match keywords having/not having apostrophe, with text strings, excluding any double-quotes enclosing those keywords

Tags: arrays, excel, regex, vba

In Excel workbook, i have a table with Keywords column that i want to match with large text strings in rows of another table column.

Keywords table:

| keywords |
| --- |
| isn't a problem |
| its same issue |
| dont recommend |
| can't bear |
| "i can hear" |
| "match maker" |

Data Table:

| Text |
| --- |
| the stolen pendrive isnt a problem |
| something i need to do everyday |
| the view isn't a problem |
| do good unto yourself |
| it's same issue with the car |
| I need a match maker for her |
| Please don't recommend the flavor |
| can you hear me? I can hear you |
| I cant bear the stupidity |
| level off fellas! |

**Edit:**

Output table: (e.g)

| Keywords | Text |
| --- | --- |
| isn't a problem | this isnt a problem with everyone?.... |
| isn't a problem | there isn't a problem for you? we do.. |
| isn't a problem | isnt a problem, that is a solution.... |
| "i can hear" | i can hear you very clearly. there.... |
| "i can hear" | i can hear the songs of the birds..... |
| dont recommend | please dont recommend him. he is a nut |
| dont recommend | we don't recommend people with refer.. |

...

I need a regex expression that can return entire string matches of keyword (multiple words) with strings in "Text" column, such that keywords with/without an apostrophe should match in the string

for e.g. `dont` and `don't` should match.
Similarly `can't` and `cant` or `its` and `it's` should match keyword with string.
Also `double-quotes enclosing keywords` should be ignored while matching with string.

The regex matches should return the entire strings.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
' Loop through each keyword and search for matches
For Each keywordCell In KeywordsRange
    Dim keyword As String
    keyword = keywordCell.Value
    
    ' Set the regex pattern based on whether the keyword is enclosed in double-quotes
    If Left(keyword, 1) = """" And Right(keyword, 1) = """" Then
        keyword = Mid(keyword, 2, Len(keyword) - 2)
        regex.pattern = "\b" & keyword & "\b"
    Else
        regex.pattern = "\b" & keyword & "\b|\b" & Replace(keyword, "'", "\'") & "\b"
    End If
    
    ' Search for matches in concatenated string
    Set matchCollection = regex.Execute(concatenatedString)
    
    ' Loop through matches and populate the output table
    ' <== WOULD BE GOOD TO COLLECT ALL MATCHES IN 2-D ARRAY AND RESIZE OUTPUT SHEET CELL WITH IT

    For Each regexMatch In matchCollection
        lrow = wkOutput.Cells(wkOutput.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        newRow.Range(lrow, 1).Value = regexMatch.SubMatches(0) ' Interviewee
        newRow.Range(lrow, 2).Value = regexMatch.Value ' Matched text
        newRow.Range(lrow, 3).Value = keyword ' Keyword
    Next regexMatch
Next keywordCell
```

**EDIT**:

P.S: The keywords are 819 keywords and the `ConcatenatedString` is a concatenated string of the text column rows (using vbcrlf as end of string), where each row can contain 2000+ characters string. The strings from this `ConcatenatedString` that match each keyword, are to be returned into an array. When all keywords are processed, the keywords with their matched array are to be returned to output sheet.

Comment: Please share what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome, the regex pattern is not pulling in matches correctly. that needs to be rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Keywords on Sheet1, text on Sheet2 and results will be on Sheet3.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub words()

    Dim ar(), arOut()
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim s As String, x As Long, c As Long, z As Long
    Dim w As String, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Call testdata
    Dim dRegex As Object, colname, dDupl As Object, m As Object
    Set dRegex = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dDupl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Sheet1 - key words
    With Sheet1
        ' find last col on header row 1
        n = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
        ' scan across header
        For c = 1 To n
            colname = Trim(.Cells(1, c))
            If Len(colname) > 0 Then
                ' last row
                n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
                ReDim ar(0 To n - 2)
                'modify for regex
                For i = 2 To n
                    s = .Cells(i, c)
                    If Len(s) = 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Nothing in keyword row " & i & " column " & c, vbCritical
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    ar(i - 2) = Replace(s, "'", "'?") ' optional
                    ar(i - 2) = Replace(ar(i - 2), """", """?")
                Next
                
                Set dRegex(colname) = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                With dRegex(colname)
                    .Global = True
                    .MultiLine = False
                    .IgnoreCase = True
                    .Pattern = "(" & Join(ar, "|") & ")"
                    'Debug.Print colname, n, .Pattern
                End With
                
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' Sheet 2 - text
    With Sheet2
        n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        z = n * dRegex.Count
        ReDim arOut(1 To z, 1 To 4)
        
        ' scan text
        i = 0
        For r = 2 To n
            s = .Cells(r, 2)
           
            ' try each regex
            For Each colname In dRegex.keys
                
                Set m = dRegex(colname).Execute(s)
                If m.Count > 0 Then
            
                    ' resize output array
                    If m.Count + 3 > UBound(arOut, 2) Then
                        ReDim Preserve arOut(1 To z, 1 To m.Count + 3)
                    End If
                
                    ' store matches
                    dDupl.RemoveAll
                    i = i + 1
                    arOut(i, 1) = s ' text in column 1
                    arOut(i, 2) = colname ' columnname in 2
                    arOut(i, 3) = .Cells(r, 1) ' person in 3
                    
                    For j = 1 To m.Count
                        ' avoid duplicate matches form global
                        w = m(j - 1)
                        If Not dDupl.exists(w) Then
                            arOut(i, j + 3) = w
                            dDupl.Add w, 1
                            x = x + 1
                        End If
                    Next
            
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
    
    ' sheet3 - results
    Dim rOut As Long: rOut = 0
    ReDim ar(1 To x, 1 To 4)
    
    With Sheet3
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array("keywords", "KeyColumn", "Person", "Text")
        For r = 1 To i
             For j = 4 To UBound(arOut, 2)
                If Len(arOut(r, j)) > 0 Then
                    rOut = rOut + 1
                    ar(rOut, 1) = arOut(r, j)
                    ar(rOut, 2) = arOut(r, 2) ' col no
                    ar(rOut, 3) = arOut(r, 3) ' person
                    ar(rOut, 4) = arOut(r, 1)
                 End If
             Next
         Next
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         .Range("A2").Resize(rOut, 4) = ar
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    MsgBox rOut & " keywords from" & n - 1 & " text lines", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub
Sub testdata()
    Dim kw, data, i
    kw = Split("isn't a problem;its same issue;dont recommend;can't bear;""i can hear"";""match maker""", ";")
    data = Split("the stolen pendrive isnt a problem;something i need to do everyday;the view isn't a problem;" & _
    "do good unto yourself;it's same issue with the car;I need a ""match maker"" for her;" & _
    "Please don't recommend the flavor;can you hear me? ""I can hear you"";I cant bear the stupidity;level off fellas!", ";")
    
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = "keywords1"
    For i = 0 To UBound(kw): Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 1) = kw(i): Next
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3) = "keywords2"
    For i = 0 To UBound(kw): Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 3) = kw(i): Next
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 5) = "keywords3"
    For i = 0 To UBound(kw): Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 5) = kw(i): Next
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 7) = "keywords4"
    For i = 0 To UBound(kw): Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 7) = kw(i): Next
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 9) = "keywords5"
    For i = 0 To UBound(kw): Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 9) = kw(i): Next

    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = "person"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "text"
    For i = 0 To UBound(data): Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, 1) = "Person" & i: Next
    For i = 0 To UBound(data): Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, 2) = data(i): Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting! What is the reason to join the keywords and then loop and match this joined keywords string with each row of data column? Just to let you know, the keywords itself are 819 keywords, where each keyword could be more than one word. Also the text column (13K+ rows) can contain rows with long strings (2000+ characters) that need to be matched and returned. Performance wise, the code should be fast.

Comment: @sifar Joining the words with `|` allows a match of any keyword in a single execute, it acts as an OR. How fast is fast , seconds rather than minutes ?

Comment: Excellent, very interesting:) I would love it to happen in seconds. I have prior code that is picking up the transcripts text from multiple word docs, that itself takes time. Do you know of any speedier way/method to improve performance? See my Edit.

Comment: i ran your code, the m.value and m.sub-matches are returning "" blanks/Empty. I think pattern is matching "".

Comment: @sifar Did you run it against the data you posted ?

Comment: Yes, the only change i made for sheet1 and sheet2 was `For r = 2 To n` as 1st row is header row of table.

Comment: Some how the pattern is matching blanks ("") instead of matching strings.

Comment: @sifar Test it by changing `With Sheet2` to `With Sheet1` and tell me what the msgbox says.

Comment: something is wrong! the arrout is being resized from 2 columns to 2000+ columns and the rows are 13K+ rows as `Text` column. The 1st value of each string from Text column is returned again. so what i mean, is all the text column strings are returned in A column, whereas blanks are returned in subsequent columns. Ideally, each keyword should return matching strings from Text column and final Output table should be of 2 columns viz., keywords (repeated) and their corresponding matching strings.

Comment: when i change `with sheet2` to `with sheet1` in code, it returns all the 819 keywords and matching blanks in columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254896/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-sifar).

Comment: see my Edit showing the output table.

Answer (score 0):

There are several changes.

- In terms of regexp pattern, "can't bear" and "can\'t bear" are exactly same
- There isn't `()` in regexp pattern, you can't get any submatch. I am not sure what's expected result in the first column of wkOutput
- `regex.Global` is used to specify whether the regular expression should match all occurrences of the pattern in the input string, rather than just the first occurrence.
- Refer cell B2 with `Range("B2")` or `Cells(2,2)`
- Keywords in column A, Text in column B, result in column D:E

```vb
    For Each keywordCell In KeywordsRange
        keyword = keywordCell.Value
        ' remove double quote
        sPattern = Replace("\b" & keyword & "\b", Chr(34), "")
        ' combine pattern with single quote
        If VBA.InStr(sPattern, "'") > 0 Then
           ' Option 1:  "can'?t bear"
           sPattern = Replace(sPattern, "'", "'?")
           ' Option 2:  "can't bear|cant bear"
           ' sPattern = Replace(sPattern, "'", "") & "|" & sPattern
        End If
        regex.Pattern = sPattern
        regex.Global = True
        Set matchCollection = regex.Execute(concatenatedString)
        If matchCollection.Count > 0 Then
            lrow = wkOutput.Cells(wkOutput.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            For Each regexMatch In matchCollection
                ' If regexMatch.SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
                '     wkOutput.Cells(lrow, 1).Value = regexMatch.SubMatches(0)
                ' End If
                wkOutput.Cells(lrow, 2).Value = regexMatch.Value
                wkOutput.Cells(lrow, 3).Value = keyword
                lrow = lrow + 1
            Next regexMatch
        End If
    Next keywordCell
```

---

**Update**

There are several changes.

- Improve code efficiency by loading data (text and keyword) into arrays and writing result to the worksheet at the end.
- The `keyword` is in the output, so the regexp patterns cannot be combined.
- Concatenating all `text` into one string can exceed VBA's `String` character limitation.
- `TXT_IN_GROUP` sets how many text lines to group into each string chunk. Adjust as needed.
- Keywords in column A, Text in column B, result in column D:E
- `|` is a delimiter to concat text string. Update it as needed if `|` is in your text.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim i, j, idx As Long
    Dim keyWord As String, sPattern As String
    Dim sTxt As String, arrKeyword, arrText
    Dim arrConTxt(), arrRes()
    ' Get text in column B
    arrText = Range([b2], [b2].End(xlDown))
    ' Concate text in group to imporve efficiency
    Const TXT_IN_GROUP = 500
    ReDim arrConTxt(CInt(UBound(arrText) / TXT_IN_GROUP))
    idx = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrText) Step TXT_IN_GROUP
        sTxt = ""
        For j = 0 To TXT_IN_GROUP - 1
            If i + j > UBound(arrText) Then Exit For
            sTxt = sTxt & "||" & arrText(i + j, 1)
        Next j
        arrConTxt(idx) = sTxt & "|"
        idx = idx + 1
    Next i
    ' Get keyword in column A
    arrKeyword = Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown))
    idx = 0
    Dim regEx As Object, oMatch As Object, matchCollection As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrKeyword)
        keyWord = arrKeyword(i, 1)
        sPattern = Replace("\|[^\|]*?" & keyWord & "[^\|]*?\|", Chr(34), "")
        sPattern = Replace(sPattern, "'", "'?")
        regEx.Pattern = sPattern
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrConTxt)
            Set matchCollection = regEx.Execute(arrConTxt(j))
            If matchCollection.Count > 0 Then
                For Each oMatch In matchCollection
                    ReDim Preserve arrRes(1, 0 To idx)
                    arrRes(0, idx) = keyWord
                    arrRes(1, idx) = Replace(oMatch.Value, "|", "")
                    idx = idx + 1
                Next oMatch
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Write matching result into column D:E
    If idx > 0 Then
        With ActiveSheet
            If idx > .Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "Too many lines to write into worksheet"
            Else
                .Range("D:E").Clear
                .Range("D1").Resize(idx, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something here. Can you let me know what is the change you have added to my previous code?

Comment: @sifar Updated the code and added note for change.

Comment: There are 819 keywords that need to be matched with 13K+ rows of strings some of which could be greater than 2000+ characters. The matched strings for each keyword need to be returned. Currently your code is taking a lot of time (each search 15 mins) at regex.execute and then writing to sheet.

Comment: The code snippet is just a demostration which keeps most of your code logic. Of course, using array will mprove code efficiency. I have updated the code.

Comment: thanks for the update. but the pattern is only returning same keyword and not the matching strings. Code also takes a lot of time, if i change the pattern to something else like regex.pattern = "(" & keyword & ")".

Comment: Have you tested the code with the sample data provided? I uploaded a screenshot of my test results. Using a pattern like "(" & keyword & ")" requires accessing submatches which can't improve efficiency. This might be the reason why your test results w/o the matching strings.  Perhaps reconsider if the business logic could be adjusted for better performance.

Comment: yes, i tested the code. However, i need the matching Text along with the keyword. I had made edits to my original post. I had shown the output table.

Comment: The keywords and matching text will be output to columns D and E (screenshot in my reply), assuming no changes to my code.

Comment: the concern is about the matching text. i think there is some misunderstand. i need the matched strings from Text column, that contain that keyword.

Comment: Finally, I get what are you looking for. :-} I have updated the code.

Comment: Interesting! Can you check this sample file? Trying to implement your suggested code. Can you help me with the output I am trying to achieve? 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z7brWX3-_exMnV_-ehpcDi4K3HjdN7HF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I got "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."

Comment: You may need to copy the entire link and paste in your browser

Comment: It's same error. Please test url with Chrome igcognito mode.

Comment: https://t.ly/6fHUn

Comment: This requirement seems more complex than the original post. Please update OP with details in the question or create a new post. This will help understand the goal.

Comment: Is there a regex pattern that can exclude any text before a ":" in  keyword and only consider as keyword, text after the ":"? I am thinking joining keyword table name with each keyword like this "keywords1:is a problem" and then join all keywords together separated by "|" as shown by CDP1802, then execute regex pattern over each text row. This way, I can split later to get keywords1 table name in output column. The Text column rows can also be joined with Person column using a delimiter ":"  and later split into 2 columns for final output table viz., Keywords, keyword table, person, text.

Comment: AFAIK, The keyword is a part of output, so the regexp patterns cannot be combined. All character in regex pattern string will be counted.

Comment: this pattern seems to be working. Just need to do a replace in keyword string to add the round brackets. [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/mkO2oX/1)